# How can I host an HTTP server in Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, httpserver

I want to host an HTTP (or, at the very least, a TCP) server using Expo for iOS and Android.

When I try to import the `http` module, I get the following error:

```
Unable to resolve module http from /home/<me>/<project>/screens/LoginModal.tsx: http could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
  ../node_modules
  1 |
> 2 | import {createServer} from "http";
...
```

Same thing happens with the other HTTP-like modules, `net`, and external libraries such as Express did not work.

How can I host an HTTP (or TCP to implement HTTP) server on Expo?  I do not need the connection to be encrypted.  I am using this for an implicit grant from OAuth2, but the token is after the # character in the URL.